# Entity Framework Core: load related data after object is queried

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

It is clear how to query an entity and include all the related data; e.g.:

```cs
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .Include(blog => blog.Owner)
        .ToList();
}
```

[REF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

My question is, given an entity that is missing some related data, how I can ask EF to fetch its related data from DB?

For instance:

```cs
var blog = context.Blogs.Find(1); // get the blog with ID=1

// how can I do something like:
blog.Include(x => x.Posts);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#explicit-loading

Comment: @GertArnold Your link to the documentation for explicit loading is the correct answer to this question.  You should re-submit it as an Answer rather than as a Comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cs
context.Entry(blog).Collection(x => x.Posts).Load();
context.Entry(blog).Reference(x => x.Owner).Load();
```

According to [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#explicit-loading), as suggested by @GertArnold

Answer (score 3):

As [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1.find?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbSet_1_Find_System_Object___) said, the retun dataType of `Find()` method is `TEntity`.

```
public virtual TEntity Find (params object[] keyValues);
```

and It means that `Find()` method hit the database and will fetch a `TEntity`. So you **can't extend** your query after `Find()` method. hence, If you wanna get related data in this query you **must** call `Include()` before any method which hit the database.
as like as below query:

```
var blog = context.Blogs.Include(x => x.Posts).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
```

As a conclusion, The way that you expected to do with `Includ()` is not possible,
but if you have to do this as `@GertArnold` said in comment, you can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#explicit-loading) way.

good luck.

Answer (score -2):

try to use this

```
var blog = context.Blogs.Include(x => x.Posts).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
```

Comment: Maybe the question was not clear, I mean, I don't want to use `Blogs` anymore, for application reasons.

Comment: it was I suppose. why don't you query from "Posts" DbSet directly?
something like this
context.Posts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BlogId== 1);

Comment: It is eager loading. To solve this problem need explicit loading